# How to show Layered Navigation For All Sub Category?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, layered-navigation

I am stuck with this, I want show Layered navigation for all sub category.

My "Is Anchor" For all sub category is enabled to Yes. Please suggest me way how I can show this.

Code for _getItemsData-->

```
    protected function _getItemsData() {

    if ($_module = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName() == "catalogsearch")
        return $this->_getItemsDataSearch();
    $key = $this->getLayer()->getStateKey() . '_SUBCATEGORIES';
    $data = $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->getCacheData($key);

    if ($data === null) {
        $category = $this->getCategory();
        /** @var $categoty Mage_Catalog_Model_Categeory */
        $categories = $this->_getChildrenCategories($category);
         //$this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()
              // ->addCountToCategories($categories);
        $data = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if ($category->getIsActive()) {
                $_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->setCurrentCategory($category)->getProductCollection()->getSize();
                //$_count = $category->getProductCount() ;
                //Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->setCurrentCategory($category)->getProductCollection()->getSize();
                if (!Mage::getStoreConfig("ajaxlist/ajaxlist/show_no_count") && !$_count) {
                    continue;
                }
                $data[] = array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($category->getName()),
                    'value' => $category->getId(),
                    'count' => $_count,
                );
            }
        }
        $tags = $this->getLayer()->getStateTags();
        $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->saveCacheData($data, $key, $tags);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Image 1- I want to show category as appear on Image 1 to Image 2

Image 2 is coming from dreamscapes.html it is sub sub category from Theme

[image: Image1]

[image: Image 2 Without category]

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. See Below code

```
protected function _getItemsData() {
    if ($_module = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName() == "catalogsearch")
        return $this->_getItemsDataSearch();
    $key = $this->getLayer()->getStateKey() . '_SUBCATEGORIES';
    $data = $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->getCacheData($key);
    if ($data === null) {
        $category = $this->getCategory();
        /** @var $categoty Mage_Catalog_Model_Categeory */

          if($categories==null)
        {

               $rootcatId  = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
               $root_cat   = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($rootcatId);
                $cat_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
                $categories = $cat_model->load($root_cat->getId())->getChildrenCategories();

        }
        else
        {
        $categories = $this->_getChildrenCategories($category); 
      }
         //$this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()
              // ->addCountToCategories($categories);
        $data = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if ($category->getIsActive()) {
                $_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->setCurrentCategory($category)->getProductCollection()->getSize();
                //$_count = $category->getProductCount() ;
                //Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->setCurrentCategory($category)->getProductCollection()->getSize();
                if (!Mage::getStoreConfig("ajaxlist/ajaxlist/show_no_count") && !$_count) {
                    continue;
                }
                $data[] = array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($category->getName()),
                    'value' => $category->getId(),
                    'count' => $_count,
                );
            }
        }
        $tags = $this->getLayer()->getStateTags();
        $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->saveCacheData($data, $key, $tags);
    }
    return $data;
}
```