# Why Magento Ajax Layered Navigation showing all category for landing page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, layered-navigation, ajax

Why Magento Ajax Layered Navigation showing all category? I don't want show other category which are not associated with category.

Comment: can you explain in detail with a screen shot

Comment: Take a look at- http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99846/how-to-show-layered-navigation-for-all-sub-category

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99974/how-to-get-all-associated-categories-of-current-category

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58501/how-to-show-layered-navigation-2-times-on-category-list-with-a-different-templat